# OLE automation in HTML (not using IE)

Tags: javascript, html, com, ole

I'm having a problem and I really need your support!
Here's the problem:
I have an application (.NET 4.0) that exposes a COM interface. Most of our clients is able to simply use the  tag in the HTML and that will launch our application; also they are able to interact with it.

Today a customer, that have a lot of Javascript rendering, informed us that using IE is not possible; in IE the page is very slow but in Google Chrome is very fast. So, they ask us how to interact with our application using Google Chrome.

I've made some searches in Google but it seems that OLE is only available in IE.
Anyone have a solution for my problem?

Basically the requirements are:

- Launch our application as Local Server using a GUID or a name;
- Be able to invoke methods in our COM interface;
- Be able to receive events from our COM interface;

Thanks a lot.